# Hago un push a un array, agrega el elemento, pero modifica los elementos que ya estaban en el array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```javascript
const quitarElementoArrSinResultado = (arrSelect, index) => {
    setArrConResultados(e=>[...e, {
        name: arrSinResutados[index],
        cantidadSolicitada: 1,
        value: arrSelect
    }])
}
```

Cuando hago el primer `push` se agrega el elemento sin problemas, pero cuando ya hago los siguientes elementos me actualiza la propiedad `value` de todos los elementos del `array`.

Comment: ¿Y dónde está el push?

Comment: Me imagino que el problema no está en esta instrucción, sino en que el arrSelect debe ser una referencia a algo (imposible saberlo sin ver el resto del código) y cuando cambias el valor de esa variable se cambia en todo el array. Proba cambiar el valor del arrSelect (sin ejecutar esta función) y se te deben cambiar igual todos los elementos del array.

Comment: Mira esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que guardaba la propiedad value como referencia por lo que se cambiaba cada que se actualizaba la variable, quedando el codigo asi:

```
const quitarElementoArrSinResultado = (arrSelect, index) => {
arrConResultados.push(
    {
      cantidadSolicitada:1,
      name:arrSinResutados[index],
      value:arrSelect.slice(0)
    }
)
```

lo importante es que cada que quiera agregar la propiedad value de cada elemento del array se ponga **.slice(0)** para que s eguarde como propiedad y no como referencia

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Además, debes adjuntar un [repro] en la pregunta. Lee [answer], [ask], y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.